# Attaching binary file to XML configuration

Tags: xml, jaxb2, mtom

I have a product configuration written in XML file. Its read/written using JAXB.

A binary file was encoded in base64 format was inserted in the XML file .
.The binary file is getting big., so want to attach it now.

Is there a simple way to attach the file efficiently to that XML file?

Comment: Do you mean like putting the binary file somewhere and storing its path in the XML?

Comment: No. If that path provides pointer within the file its o.k. I want to generate a single big  file that includes the binary attachment and the xml metadata.